# Can I use a signed jar to establish a SSL connection?

Tags: java, ssl, self-signed

I am using a self-signed certificate to establish a SSL connection between an application and my server. Now I'm loading a truststore from jar's resources.
Can I sign a jar using my sertificate and then use some magic to create a SSL context without packing a truststore into my client?

Answer (score 0):

No. A signing certificate is not the same thing as an SSL certificate.